# Using Python to start a browser (Chromium) and change the url

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, chromium

I am trying to write a script that makes it possible to change the url of an active process.

So for instance, I am starting my browser using:

```
browser = Popen(["chromium", "http://www.google.com"])
```

After an X interval I want to change the url of browser.

I've tried allot of things to get this result but nothing has succeeded so far. (stdin.write / put (PIPE) etc etc.).

```
browser = sh.Command('uzbl-browser')(print_events=True, config='-', uri=current_browser_url, _bg=True)
browser.process.stdin.put('uri http://www.google.nl' + '\n')
```

I'm hoping you can help me out with this.

Regards,

Wesley.

Comment: Try: `webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com')`

Comment: What do you want to do with the browser? Do you need more scripting or just changing the URL will do? Do you need a real browser with Javascript and styling, or will the HTML do?

Comment: What I am trying to create a simple Digital Signage system for a Raspberry Pi. I've got the video part working using OmxPlayer. But now I have to create a simple browser interface that shows a twitterfeed (html page) and some static JPG images etc.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `selenium` to automate this process although you could use `webbrowser` too:

```
from selenium.webdriver import *;

chrome = Chrome() # create browser
chrome.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `import webbrowser` and use function `webbrowser.open`

Here's an example of opening a music playlist:

```
import webbrowser
gaana= 'http://gaana.com/playlist/gaana-dj-bollywood-top-50-1'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(gaana)
```

Answer (score 0):

i am working on ubuntu 16.04 and i solve this problem by using geckodriver.exe file. **these steps are very simple please read caefully.**

:: at first you have to install selenium by typing this command on terminal>>

```
        for python2:-  python -m pip install --user selenium
        for python3:-  python3 -m pip install --user selenium
```

:: next step download geckodriver using link given below >>

```
       https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

:: since i am using ubuntu so i download **geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz**
    now  extract it.

:: now in the python code for firefox browsing add these lines >>

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/home/aman/Downloads/geckodriver')
 url = str(raw_input("enter a valid url :: "))
 browser.get(url) #example :: url = https://www.google.com
 browser.close()
```

::for chrome browser >>

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 browser = webdriver.chrome(executable_path = '/home/aman/Downloads/geckodriver')
 url = str(raw_input("enter a valid url :: "))
 browser.get(url) #example :: url = https://www.google.com
 browser.close()
```

:: in my pc i extract geckodriver in **/home/aman/Downloads/geckodriver** so you have to put whole path for geckodriver file where you extract your file.

:: now run this python file on python2.7,for python3 replace raw_input with input. i hope this will definitely work for you.