# Control chromium kiosk mode url from python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

[Using Python to start a browser (Chromium) and change the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123632/using-python-to-start-a-browser-chromium-and-change-the-url)

The linked question is asking exactly what I want but I don't know how to implement the answer that is just to uses Selenium.

I just need to load chromium in kiosk mode and load a local html page I have does this with `os.system('chromium-browser --kiosk file://.....')` but this loads a new window/tab every time so it's not efficient or fast

Comment: The question you linked to uses `Popen` from [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). That allows you to communicate with the process and kill it.

Comment: Do you mean this line browser = Popen(["chromium", "http://www.google.com"]) because didn't work for him. I don't what to start a new window every time I need to display a page I just what t reload the view. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add options to selenium's chromedriver, similar to how you would using `os.system`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://example.com")
```

To refresh or reload the page repeatedly, you could do `driver.get(url)` or `driver.refresh()` in a `while True` loop.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the chromedrive to work on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me..

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

 option = Options()
 option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
 option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
 option.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
 option.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
 option.add_argument("--kiosk")
 option.add_argument("--disable-password-manager-reauthentication")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver.exe",0,option)
```